# When i am creating object ,compiler gives error C4430

Tags: visual-c++

I am getting these two errors

## Error # 01:

error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'mainObj'

## Error # 02

error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

> i have following classes
>
> 1. Main
>
>    ---
> 2. Customer
>
>    ---
> 3. CNode
>
>    ---

when i create pointer object of class 'CNode' in class 'Customer' ,there is no error. But when i create non pointer object  of  Main class in Customer class
,compiler gives above two errors.
while 'Main' class have a main fuction.

please help me out to resolve these errors.

## Main.h

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
#include<conio.h>
#include<fstream>
#include<iomanip>
#include <sstream>
#include "Customer.h"
using namespace std;
class Main
{
        int acc;
        int total = 0;
        int rtotal = 0;
        int sum = 0;

public:
    Main();
    void design();
    void welcome();
    string passcin();
    void login_des();
    void admin_account();
    void add_staff();
    void delete_staff(int);
    void search_staff(int);
    void update_staff(int);
    void room_display();
    void room_book();
    void checkout();
        int main();
};
```

## Customer.h

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include "Main.h"
#include "Node.h"



class Customer
{
    CNode *head, *tail, * temp;
    Main mainObj;

public:

    Customer();

    bool search(string, string);
    void updateAccount(string, string);
    CNode* inputNode();
    void custAccount(string);
    void createAccount();
    void createAccount(CNode *);
    void addCust();
    void deleteCust(int sno);
    void searchCust(int sno);
    void updateCust(int sno);
    void displayCust();
    CNode* retriveAllCust();
};
```

## Node.h

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
class CNode
{
     string name, email, pass, roomNo, phoneNo, country, creditCardName, cardNo;
bool bookFlag;
CNode *prev, *next;
int length;
public:
CNode();
CNode(string n, string e, string ps, string r, string pn, string country, string creditName, string creditNo, bool bookFlag);
CNode(string n, string e, string ps, string pn, string country);

string getName();
string getPass();
CNode* getNextNode();
void display();
void addCust();
string retriveCust();

friend class Customer;
};
```

I have put a semi colon before mainObj
like

> ;Main mainObj;

error occors in Customer Class
in

> Main mainObj;

Comment: You have a circular dependency between .h files, that can't come to a good end.  It is not obvious why a Customer needs to know anything about "Main", it certainly shouldn't.  Start tackling the problem there first, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle

Comment: I got it, you are right. Thanks for your help